# Create a Sharepoint BCS Connection to SFDC

Tags: soap-api

I am trying to connect Sharepoint 2013 to Salesforce using OOTB functionallity.

Specifically, I'd like to create an External Content Type using a Business Connectfivtiy Services (BCS) Connection.

There are a couple of great YouTube videos that demonstrate this functionallity but they don't go into the detail of configuring the actual connection.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JacwLbBKI5U
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBsNqYTUDqY

I get to this form in Sharepoint Configuration and I don't really know where to go from here.

[image]

I've tried using the Entrerrise WSDL URL and an API User credentials but it does not seem to work.  Has anyone done this type of integration before?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks